# How to treat `int` like an object in an array

Tags: java, arrays

As most of you know, when you make a `int[]`hold variables of type `int`, the array is not updated when you change the `int` variables it is holding due to how primitive data types are copied rather than pointed.  Is there any way to make this happen however? Possibly

```
Integer int[] = new Integer[] {Integer f1...};
```

I want to be able to make an `int[]` but when I change the variables it holds elsewhere in the program, they are changed within the `int[]` as well.

Comment: `Integer[]` does exist, but since `Integer` is immutable (i.e. you can't change the value that a given `Integer` object holds) it behaves very similar to `int[]` with regard to mutability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely no way with an `int[]`.  You could create your own mutable integer class to do it, or abuse `AtomicInteger` to do it.

```
 AtomicInteger[] array = new AtomicInteger[5];
 array[0] = new AtomicInteger(6);
 array[0].set(4);
 System.out.println(array[0].get()); // returns 4
```

Comment: in addition, [commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has `MutableInt`

Comment: Would this hold true with `String[]` as well?

Comment: @David, `String` is immutable, so it'd be no better off.  You could use `StringBuilder` or the like.  (But generally, wanting to mutate is a bad sign in the first place.)

Comment: What you basically need is a holder class. Something like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Holder.html... You can verywell create one yourself easily...

Comment: I just want my arrays to update so I can use them within the program instead of having to wait till the end of the method to make them

Comment: What do you mean?  Why do you need to mutate things instead of setting them up the first time?

Comment: Well, what I was trying to do was create `int` variables, add them to a `int[]`, and make it so changing the `int` variables would change the values in my `int[]` as well.  I now realize I'm pretty bad at java, as I could just deal directly with the locations in my `int[]` rather than anything with teh variables..... live and learn :D

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach that works for all types is to use an array that holds 1-element arrays.

```
int[][] pos = new int[3][1];
int[] x = new int[] { 3 };
int[] y = new int[] { 4 };
int[] z = new int[] { 0 };

pos[0] = x;
pos[1] = y;
pos[2] = z;

x[0] = 42; // Translate in x direction

System.out.println( "x=" + pos[0][0] ); // Prints "42"
```

However, it is usually better to define a class that provides accessors and mutators with meaningful names.

```
public class Position {
  private x, y, z;
  public int x() { return x; }
  public setX( int x0 ) { x = x0; }
  ... etc
}
```

Comment: I'm a new java student, 2d arrays scare me haha

Comment: @David - They don't have to be scary. Your question mentions pointing. In Java, you can visualize a 2D array as an array of pointers to rows of data. You can create a rectangular 2D array. But you can also create a 2D array whose pointers might be null, or with rows of different lengths. That's the worst of it.